# HTTP client status code always returns undefined

Tags: angular

I am creating an application in angular. I have a service to call rest api's, whenever I am trying console or alert the status code of the response I am getting undefined. Although if I console the data returns from rest api, it successfully shows the data. Please see the code below and suggest how can I get the status code of a HTTP response.

```
export type AjaxResponse = {
  response: {
    [key: string]: any
  },
  status: number
}


apiCall(
    data: any,
    url: any,
    method: 'DELETE' | 'GET' | 'HEAD' | 'POST' | 'JSONP' | 'PUT',
    isRawUrlFormat: boolean = false
  ) {
    // Checking if the provide url is in raw format or not
    if (isRawUrlFormat == false) {
      url = environment.API_URL + "/" + url;
    }

    let requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    let token = this._authTokenService.getUserToken();

    if (token != undefined || token != null || token != '') {
      requestHeaders = requestHeaders.set(
        "Authorization",
        "Bearer " + token
      );
    }

    const requestOptions: {
      headers: HttpHeaders,
      responseType: 'json'
    } = {
      headers: requestHeaders,
      responseType: 'json'
    }

    let request$: Observable<AjaxResponse>;

    switch (method) {
      case 'POST':
        request$ = this._http.post<AjaxResponse>(url, data, requestOptions);
        break;
      case 'PUT':
        request$ = this._http.put<AjaxResponse>(url, data, requestOptions);
        break;
      default:
        request$ = this._http.request<AjaxResponse>(method, url, requestOptions);
    }




    return request$.pipe(
      //timeout(environment.AJAX_TIMEOUT),
      map(apiResult => {
        const status : number = apiResult.status;
        console.log(status);
        return apiResult;
      }),
      catchError(error => {
        const status : number = error.status;
        console.log(status)
        return throwError(error)
      })
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear how you're making this call. I see that you've created a `type` for an `AjaxResponse` and then you have an additional function for `apiCall`. But, it's not clear what you're actually using to initiate the request.

Since you tagged angular, you should be using the `HttpClient` for you Http Calls. If you're trying to use something else, you'll have to defer to their documentation.

However, to answer your question, to get the actual status code in Angular using `HttpClient`, you can do the below:

Adding `{ observe: 'response' }` will give you the full payload instead of just the response.

*Angular does not return the status code to you unless you actually tell it to. Otherwise, you will only get the body of the response*

```
HttpClient.get<T>(<url>, { observe: 'response' }).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res.status); // <-- status code
});
```

Additionally, you could use angular `HttpInterceptor` if you are trying to do some type of error handling based on your response.